# Catch href, but it doesnt "appear" a href

Tags: javascript, arrays, hyperlink, href

I was using this code

```
 var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="page=fleet"]');

var hrefs = Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(link){
  return link.href;
});

alert(hrefs.join('\n'));
```

It worked perfect, but some hrefs, appear as tooltip, if I look inside the html code with a html editor, all the others href have a diferent color, but the hrefs inside the `<a class` doesnt have color, its look like a normal text, so I think because this the code above doesnt work

```
<a class="tooltip_sticky"

<a href="link">LINK</a>

</a>
```

Is there a way to say that the href of the LINK its a valid href to catch?

Comment: That last code block makes no sense. It is invalid HTML.

Comment: And SO syntax highlighting is making it totally obvious.

Comment: I don't see how that is the problem. Depending on how the browser resolves this error, it's either a valid href in the outer A (if the browser ignores the faulty `<a`), or a valid href in the second A (if the browser closes the first A first). Either way, the Javascript should be able to find it in the DOM.

Comment: Epascarello ??? |

Virus, yes if i use a html editor the syntax highlight change the color of the href outside the tooltip, but the href inside, has the same color as text | 


Mr Lister, yes, but in this case, its now showing the hrefs inside the tooltip :|

Comment: hey guys, take a look at this image and you will understand -> http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/7141/9dgu.jpg

Comment: But where you point to and say "don't show" aren't A elements at all. All that is just the content of the name attribute of the first element in the TD.